# Rotation and cropping an image IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am performing rotation on an `UIImageView` and then i try to crop a part of it and save it as an `UIImage`. The `UIImageView` rotates however it always crops the same part of the photo. So the cropping does not take into account the image rotation. What am i doing wrong?

```
//rotate image 
CGRect new = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(5);
[photo setTransform:rotation];

// crop image 
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([photo.image CGImage], new);
UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

// display crop bounds 
UIView* faceBounds = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:new];
faceBounds.layer.borderWidth = 2;
faceBounds.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```

Comment: Because the transformation is applied when rendering the image-view to the screen and not on the image data itself.

Comment: I see.. and how could i fix this?

Comment: It also seems as if you are using the wrong unit for the rotation angle. I guess you mean to rotate by 5 degrees. For doing that, you will have to convert that angle into radians. A simple conversion would be `angleInRadians = angleInDegrees * M_PI / 180`

Comment: I just gave that as an example, i realised that i need to convert degrees to radian's. Spent so much time on this, but thank you yet again for your help.

Comment: My pleasure - hope things work smooth from this point on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following snippet for rotating image data.

The input data is `inAngle` (angle in radians) and `inImage` (`UIImage` instance).

What this does, it creates an image context, applies the transformation to it and draws the original image into that context. The resulting image data will now be stored in `resultImage`.

The first three lines handle the calculation of the bounding result image frame.

```
UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)];
rotatedViewBox.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(inAngle);
CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2.0f, rotatedSize.height / 2.0f);
CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, inAngle);
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0f, -1.0f);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-inImage.size.width / 2.0f,
                                      -inImage.size.height / 2.0f,
                                      inImage.size.width,
                                      inImage.size.height),
                                      inImage.CGImage);
UIImage *resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the snippet of code. I want to ask, where does the image pivot from? (0,0?) and if so how can i make it pivot from the image center?. Also, if the image is e.g. jpeg format, will i have to modify the 'bitmap' part? (code works as it is for jpeg but just wondering).

Comment: It rotates around the center of the image. The source format does not matter as long as UIImage properly *understands* it.

Comment: That `bitmap` is a bit misleading. What this is is a graphics context for drawing in memory (as opposed to on screen).

Comment: @Till I am trying your code, but it's not working. I don't understand how CGRectMake locates the x and y?

Comment: @Odelya this code works fine, rest assured. What exactly is your problem? I do not get you on "I dont understand how CGRectMake locates the x and y".

Comment: @Till The code rotates the image for me, but doesn't crop it!

Comment: @Odelya That is by design, it is not supposed to crop anything. You should read the original question for getting the exact point.

Comment: @Till so where should the cropping be done? before or after the rotation?

Comment: @Odelya that entirely depends on your needs. I would like to suggest you post a new question that describes exactly what you are trying to achieve. It often helps to include a mocked image showing how your results are supposed to look like.

Comment: @Till - i keep hearing that the frame property should not be used after applying a transformation. Still, your code seems to work properly and i dont understand half of what a transformation is. would you mind explaining why it is ok for you to access `rotatedBox.frame.size` after setting `rotatedBox.transform`? TIA, katzenhut

Comment: How to CROP if image is rotated , Anyone here with answer ?

Answer (score -1):

This is too late for now but For now someone can try [this](https://github.com/SurpriseWave/SWImageRotation)

Comment: This "answer" is more like a comment. We highly discourage such link only answers.

Comment: I think it should be considered as comment. I have developed that library and also explained code in that link so I think no need to repeat the step here. @Till