# How can I get a "screenshot" of a rotated rectangle

Tags: ios, core-graphics

This is an example photo I am using. I am drawing the black rectable with a UIView so I have the angles and sizes figured out but I'm having a hard time getting a perfect crop to match this view.

[image]

What is the best way for me to capture a screenshot of a rotated image? I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061773/879119) but it's not a perfect "crop" of the black outline. It seems to just rotate from the center.

This is what it looks like when I try that answer, notice it's a different crop portion:

[image]